# Setting multiple Email to client people picker using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-online

I had set an email address to my client people picker using following code:

```
var userName = "addressA@in.com";    
var ppDiv = $(searchTab).find("div[title='Enter names or email addresses...']");                
var ppEditor = ppDiv.find("input[title='Enter names or email addresses...']");              
var spPP = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv.attr('id')];             
ppEditor.val(userName);
spPP.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
```

But, here I want to set multiple email addresses to people picker. For example,

```
var userName = "addressA@in.com; addressB@in.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the same method with another userName has done the trick.

```
var userName = "addressA@in.com; addressB@in.com"
var splitNames = userName.split(';');
for(var i=0;i<splitNames.length;i++){
    var ppDiv = $(searchTab).find("div[title='Enter names or email addresses...']");                
    var ppEditor = ppDiv.find("input[title='Enter names or email addresses...']");              
    var spPP = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv.attr('id')];             
    ppEditor.val(splitNames[i]);
    spPP.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
}
```

Hope this helps.